# How can i filter out unique packets based on a value which reside in payload portion of packet?

Tags: networking, tcp, udp, ip, wireshark

Wireshark - how can i filter out unique packets based on a value which reside in payload portion of packet?

For example if i have 3 UDP packates :

1. UDP1 : Payload = "xyz"
2. UDP2 : Payload = "abc"
3. UDP3 : Payload = "xyz"

I want to apply filter such that wireshark displays only packets which are not having repeated value in the payload:

Expected output : ( if traversing from top)

1. UDP1 : Payload = "xyz"
2. UDP2 : Payload = "abc"

Answer (score 0):

To filter message content you can use the display filter for the protocol registered as "data":
 `data==xyz`

For UDP packets:

```
udp && data==xyz
```

Example (when I want to filter using the hex value of data):

```
udp && data==17:03:01:00:20:87:a0:44
```